# Medical POA and a Home Health Aid

Tags: united-states, medical, new-jersey

Imagine a standard POA for medical has been given to an adult son for his parent to become effective when the parent cannot speak for him/her self. It has been determined by several doctors that the parent has dementia and cannot speak for herself.

Would the POA for medical enable the adult son to bring in a home health aid into the parent's home against her wishes?

My guess is no because the parent still control's her  home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct (although an aggressive person could argue that the parent would never have the wherewithal to sue to complain about it).

The adult son really needs to have a guardianship established by a court, because a POA isn't sufficient to do what needs to be done.

Usually, an agent in a POA has priority for appointment as a guardian, and if the facts are clear, it isn't necessary to hard to get a guardianship established. But it does take money and it isn't instantaneous.